# Autoupdate specific cell, not entire column/range - VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, dropdown, auto-update

**Goal**

I would like the **Autoopdate code** and **Code** only to take the specific changes into account and not update entire column.

**Description and Problem**

Column C contains 4 different values (Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4). Whenever a user chooses a type the type (in the form of an array) is outputted in column D for that specific row. A user can then manually change the type by in column D afterwards.

If a user then chooses a value in column C, all the cells in column D will autoupdate and populate with the original values. I don't want this. Only the specific row should autoupdate the type in column D.

Is that possible?

**Autoopdate code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Call AutoDropdown
    End If
End Sub
```

**Code**

```
Sub AutoDropdown()

Dim PersonSource As Range
Dim PersonSourceTotal As Range
Dim PersonCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim SelectionArray(1 To 4) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

arr1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
arr2 = Array("E", "F", "G", "H")
arr3 = Array("I", "J", "K", "L")
arr4 = Array("M", "N", "O", "P")

SelectionArray(1) = Join(arr1, "--")
SelectionArray(2) = Join(arr2, "--")
SelectionArray(3) = Join(arr3, "--")
SelectionArray(4) = Join(arr4, "--")
AllSelections = Join(SelectionArray, ",") 'group all selections for data validation
On Error Resume Next

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = "sheet1" Or ws.Name = "sheet2" Or ws.Name = "sheet3" Then

        Set PersonSourceTotal = ws.Range("D2:D200")

        With PersonSourceTotal.Offset(0, -2)
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, PersonSourceTotal.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        Set PersonSource = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

        For Each PersonCell In PersonSource
            Debug.Print (PersonCell)
            varname = PersonCell.Offset(0, -3)
            Debug.Print (varname)
            ID = PersonCell.Offset(0, -2)
                If varname <> "" And ID <> "" Then
                    Select Case PersonCell.Offset(i, -1).Value
                        Case "Type1"
                            With PersonCell.Validation
                            Debug.Print (PersonCell)
                                .Delete
                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                            End With
                            PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(1)
                        Case "Type2"
                            With PersonCell.Validation
                                .Delete
                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                            End With
                            PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(2)
                        Case "Type3"
                            With PersonCell.Validation
                                .Delete
                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                            End With
                            PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(3)
                        Case "Type4"
                        With PersonCell.Validation
                                .Delete
                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                            End With
                            PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(4)
                        Case Else
                            MsgBox "No Type was entered on Column C"
                    End Select
                'Else
                '   MsgBox "Remember to add VarName and ID"
                End If
        Next PersonCell
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```